# WPF RibbonControlLibrary

Tags: wpf

Can anyone tell me how to download Wpf RibbonControlLibrray and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Code Project seems to have the [source and a pretty comprehensive demonstration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ribboncontrol.aspx)

Hope that's what you're after

Comment: I think your link rocks : +1 (hehe)